# Best Raspberry Pi OS for ROS Noetic

Tags: 20.04, raspberrypi, ubuntu-mate, ros

I installed ROS Noetic on Raspberry Pi OS ( my RP is a 64-bit B4 model) but I cannot run some commands it so I decided to change it to Ubuntu. I can install Ubuntu mate or Ubuntu itself for this purpose using the links below:
https://ubuntu-mate.org/download/arm64/
https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi
but the problem is that both of them provide Ubuntu 22.04 Jammy Jellyfish. I already tried ROS Noetic on 22.04 for my PC , I know it is not compatible and I need 20.04 for ROS noetic. Now the question is: Can I find Ubuntu 20.04 for RP somewhere or do you recommend any other OS for RP useful for ROS Noetic?

Thank you!

Comment: Recommendations about anything other than Ubuntu are obviously off-topic here.

Comment: All version of Ubuntu images are found at cdimages.ubuntu.com; all *supported* versions of Ubuntu-MATE will be found there too, but *unsupported flavors* are removed from the site.  eg. https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/20.04/release/

Comment: 20.04 is still available for download - go to the official Ubuntu download page, and click on *see our alternative downloads* and you’ll see a link to 20.04.5 download.